# Best practice deploying Stored Procedures to multi DB with same structure?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, multi-tenant

We have one website currently being used by 3 clients. We have 3 different versions of the same source code which is calling 3 different databases. So,

1) Client A access "http://custA.weblink.com" will access "CustA" Database

2) Client B access "http://custB.weblink.com" will access "CustB" Database

3) Client C access "http://custC.weblink.com" will access "CustC" Database

All databases have the same structure, table design and stored procedures. Only the data is different.

The issue is, when I need to do deployment for stored procedures, I need to repeat the backup and perform deployment 3 times. It's not really hard even when there are lots of stored procedures need to be deployed but doesn't seems like a good practice.

Now I only have 3 clients, what if in the future I have 10? I need to repeat backup and deployment 10 times which is time consuming and it's hard to guarantee that all stored procedures in all databases will always be the same.

In this type of case where I have existing multi applications and databases, what could be the good practice or measurements to take to make the situation better? I don't think my company will allow making huge changes like merging all clients data into one database and re-write application flow to get the right data.

I thought about creating one main database without any data. All the Stored Procedures script will be deployed there. And each of the existing "CustA", "CustB" and "CustC" DB, I will use to `EXEC` method to call Stored Procedure from main database to process the data in the relevant DB. Like this:

1) Main database

```
USE [MainDatabase]
ALTER PROCEDURE USP_GetCustomerById
@CustId BIGINT

SELECT * FROM [Customer] WHERE Id = @CustId
```

2) CustA database (Same flow for CustB and CustC database)

```
USE [CustA]
ALTER PROCEDURE USP_GetCustomerById
@CustId BIGINT

EXEC MainDatabase.dbo.USP_GetCustomerById @CustId
```

Will there be any impact if I do so?

Comment: " I don't think my company will allow making huge changes like merging all clients data into one database and re-write application flow to get the right data." This is a known and proven pattern called 'multitenancy'. Your three / five / ten / 1000 databases are going to get out of sync and that's going to cause you more issues than rewriting multi tenant. Just to be clear: you are hosting the database for these clients - will you ever deploy your database to a client site?

Comment: Alternatively, you need to improve your deployment process. (this is another new concept - continuous database deployment). For eample If you could click a button and deploy to all DB's that'd be good right? The latest version of SQL Server Data Tools has schema compare built in, which is a thing that lets you generate change scripts to get databases in line (with inbuilt checking to stop it dropping populated tables etc.). I suggest you download this free tool and take a look. (But install it in a different environment to BIDS)

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever considered to use visual studio to create an SQL Server Database Project? Here you can import for instance the first server ClientA settings for a single Database. It will import (schemas,objects,views,indexes and so on) And then you can setup different deployment servers. You can also compare Source and destination (A and B) to each other, to see if you have differences. (I

**Example on deploying on Database to multiple servers**
[image]

As you can see in my picture i have the whole structure for one database. In the bottom of the Solution Explorer you can see i have something called PROD and TEST. This is actually two different servers. You could create the 3 servers you need and then you can just press deploy.

**Example on Schema compare**
[image]

Here i have compared a source with my project. Then i can import my changes i made on ClientA and inject them to my project, so i can deploy them to the other servers.